# SQL - create array of values matching another value

Tags: php, mysql, sql

**UPDATE: WORKING SOLUTIONS**

**Getting an array type:**

```
column1, CONCAT('[', GROUP_CONCAT(column2), ']') AS array FROM table GROUP BY column1
```

And this returns a column named array with following results: [x,y,z]

**Getting an object type:**

```
column1, CONCAT('[', GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('{ property_A:', column2, ', property_B:', column3, '}')), ']') AS object FROM table GROUP BY column1
```

And this returns a column named object with following results: [{property_A: x, property_B: z},{property_A: y, property_B: w}]

**ORIGINAL QUESTION**

I have SQL table like that:

```
N | B
1 | z
1 | w
1 | y
2 | x
2 | k
```

how has to be the query that returns something like that:

```
N | C => alias of collection of B
1 | [z, w, y]
2 | [x, k]
```

Thanks

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: Not a big expert, but I suppose MySql is the right answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not "return arrays" in SQL, you return *datasets* or sets of tuples. So you would request,

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE N = 1;
```

and it would return

```
z
w
y
```

In MySQL there exists the `GROUP_CONCAT` function so that

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(value) FROM `table`
```

would return

```
'z,w,y'
```

and, from MySQL 5.7.22+, you can actually return an array (rather, a JSON array) using

```
 SELECT JSON_ARRAYAGG(value) FROM `table` WHERE N=1;

 ["z", "w", "y"]
```

Ordinarily you would just cycle the dataset and get your array. This is actually possible with ready-made functions in many languages, and since you mentioned PHP, it is very easy to do it using PDO:

```
// This is the first column, so it has the number 0.
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT value FROM `table` WHERE N = :n');
$stmt->execute([ ':n' => 1 ]);
$arr  = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN, 0);
```

Now $arr is a PHP array: `[ 'z', 'w', 'y' ]`.

Comment: Yes, it's not exactly what I wanted, but it's good enough. I can parse the result in PHP once I've fetched the data. Thank you.

Comment: Um, wait. You wanted a PHP array? Amending answer...

Comment: Actually it seems that MariaDB doesn't have JSON_ARRAYAGG, so I found a good alternative with this script:
SELECT column1, CONCAT('[', GROUP_CONCAT(column2), ']') AS column2 FROM table GROUP BY column1;
and this one does the job perfectly. Thank you!

Comment: One more update:
in case you need to create an object style, this is the script I've found:
SELECT c1, CONCAT('[', GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('{ c2:', c2, ', c3:', c3, '}')), ']') AS object FROM table GROUP BY c1